# Busy waiting with semaphores?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex, semaphore

Imagine *n* threads are running this code:

```
int counter = 0;
sem1 = Semaphore(1);

void barrier () {
    sem1.wait();
    counter+=1;
    sem1.post();
    while(counter<=n);
}
```

My professor said there is busy waiting, but why?

The first thread will reach the while loop, the other *n-1* threads will stop at `sem1.wait();`. The semaphore will let them enter a queue for waiting and wake them up when `sem1>0`, so where is the busy waiting happening?

Comment: `while(counter<=n) ; ` is the busy wait.

Comment: @PSkocik No, to be more precise he said: There is an endless loop AND busy wait.

Comment: Well yeah.`while(counter<n) ;` would be a busy wait for the other threads to do their increment, and with `<=n` it never ends.

Comment: An endless loop is usually a busy-wait. But I guess the point is that it's inefficient to have all threads poll that variable over and over instead of sleeping. Also, two semaphores isn't a critical section, so in case writing/reading counter isn't atomic, then the variable might get read incorrectly as a race condition.

Comment: Re "*would be a busy wait for the other threads to do their increment*", Not necessarily. The compiler could optimize that loop into `if (counter>n) { while (1); }`. It's just plain wrong.

Comment: @ikegami That's a good point. What I had said would require an _Atomic counter.

Comment: @PSkocik Sounds like they want all threads to wait until they call `barrier`? If so, it can be done with just the one semaphore: `sem1 = Semaphore(1-n); void barrier() { sem_post(sem1); sem_wait(sem1); sem_post(sem1); }`

Answer (score 0):

A blocking system call will not schedule the blocked thread for execution -- it uses absolutely no CPU -- until the unblocking condition is satisfied.

Say you `read` from a socket. If there's no data to be read, `read` will block until data arrives, and the thread that called `read` will sleep until then.

A busy wait loop is a loop where a condition is continually checked, using up a lot of CPU. This is what `while(counter<=n);` does. It will continually read `counter` and `n` and compare them, using up the CPU and other resources. In general, this is a horrible approach.

And that's assuming `while(counter<=n);` works as intended. The compiler is free to implement that as `if (counter>n) { while (1); }`, which definitely does not work as intended. So `while(counter<=n);` is not just inefficient; it's just plain wrong.

It looks like you want all threads to wait until they call `barrier`. If so, it can be done with just the one semaphore.

```c
// We want waits to block until n posts have been made.
sem1 = Semaphore_new(1-n);

void barrier() {
   // Increment the sem count.
   Semaphore_post(sem1);

   // Wait until the sem count reaches one.
   // This will only happen after every thread has called barrier().
   Semaphore_wait(sem1);

   // After every threads has called barrier(),
   // the sem count will reach one,
   // and one of the threads will wake up.
   // That thread will wake up another thread,
   // and so on until all the threads are awake.
   Semaphore_post(sem1);
}
```